# Выборка с двумя внешними ключами в связаной таблице

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Возникла проблема при выборке данных. Имеется две таблицы User и Follower.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE follower (
follower_id integer,
followed_id text,
FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES user(id),
FOREIGN KEY (followed_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

Собственно не могу понять, как сделать выборку вида: (id подписчика, имя подписчика, id на кого подписан, имя на кого подписан).

Сейчас получилось выводить только: (id подписчика, имя подписчика, id на кого подписан). С помощью:

```
SELECT id, name, followed_id FROM follower INNER JOIN user ON (follower_id = user.id);
```

Как вывести еще и имя на кого подписан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.name, u2.id, u2.name
FROM follower f
INNER JOIN user u1 /* subscriber */
  ON (f.follower_id = u1.id);
INNER JOIN user u2 /* followed person */
  ON (f.followed_id = u2.id);
```